# Interacting With One-dimensional Objects

Tags: string-theory, spacetime-dimensions

If I had a one dimensional object, lets say a string (the really small kind) that I managed to grow to the size of 1 meter in front of me. Would I be able to see or touch it? How would I be able to see a one-dimensional object? To be more precise, when I see a thread it has some degree of thickness. With a one-dimensional object there is no thickness. Would I still be able to see it?

Comment: The answer to this question depends entirely on the properties of the object...

Comment: What do you expect to happen. That might give us more insight into what it is  you want to know. Regards

Comment: @CountTo10 I edited the question. Is that better?

Comment: Thanks Yes,  I wrote a short answer, because you asked a direct question, and I think there is a direct answer.  I don't know much about string theory, but unless we can see an electron directly, (and not the charge from it you might see in electron microscopes,) we definitely should not be able to see the even smaller strings below the size of the electron. This gets us into philosophy more than physics, in my opinion,  because we have little/no experimental data.

Comment: A one-dimensional structure makes sense only if at minimum one end of the string interacts with the surrounding. More I elaborated here https://www.academia.edu/19657550/Complex_one-dimensional_structures_of_space

Comment: This question cannot be answered because no physical theory has any "one-dimensional object" of which it makes sense to ask whether you can "see" it. The tag string-theory suggests you're thinking about the "strings" of string theory, but the relevant objects of string theory are not the strings themselves, but the quantum states generated by them - and it is those, not the strings, that are conceivably observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No is the straightforward  answer,  you should not be able to see a truly 1 dimensional object.

I am taking you literally here, no mark, or point can be seen if it is truly one dimensional.

A single point, such as an object's centre of mass is actually zero dimensional, because it does not stretch in any direction by any distance

But it may well be that string theory, whether it is ever established experimentally, never needs to be involved. If an electron is a point particle, we won't be able to see that either.

Comment: So would there be any way of detecting it?

Comment: In the past I, as a non expert, would have said no. But smarter people than me are looking at ways of , for instance, seeing if gravity at small scales changes from its usual $1/r^2$ force to say $1/r^3$ or $1/r^4$, which we could detect as it spreading out into small curled up dimensions, but it would be weaker then in our 3D world, as it has more degrees of freedom on a tiny scale. We might detect 1 D space in the same indirect way.

Answer (score -1):

No one object is really one- nor two-dimensional. Point, edge and surface are geometrical abstractions. But it is possible to define or construct one-dimensional objects.

Imagine a rope with ends in the form of hooks. To stretch the rope you can use two eyelets. By this you designed an one-dimensional object with which you are able to interact through its ends. So in our three-dimensional world it is possible to work with one-dimensional objects.

More see my elaboration [Complex one-dimensional structures in space](https://www.academia.edu/19657550/Complex_one-dimensional_structures_of_space).